# How to load values into Dictionary using { }

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Is is possible to load values into Dictionary using { } ?

This fails

```
static Dictionary<byte, byte> dict = new Dictionary<byte, byte>() { new KeyValuePair<byte, byte>(1, 1) };
```

This does not fail so I suspect there is syntax for loading in  { }

```
static Dictionary<byte, byte> dic1252expand = new Dictionary<byte, byte>() { };
```

This is sample syntax that works

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }; 
KeyValuePair<byte, byte> kvp = new KeyValuePair<byte, byte>(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is working:

```
Dictionary<byte, byte> dict = new Dictionary<byte, byte>() { { 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 } };
```

Comment: Yes it works.  I have to wait 4 minutes to accept the answer.

Answer (score 25):

If you give someone a fish, they have a fish; if you teach them how to catch fish, you don't need to give them fish. All the answers posted are *correct*, but none tells you *how to figure out the answer for yourself*.

The collection initializer syntax in C# is a "syntactic sugar"; it is just a more pleasant way to write some boring code. When you write:

```
C c = new C() { p, q, { r, s }, {t, u, v} };
```

That is the same as if you had written:

```
C c;
C temporary = new C();
temporary.Add(p);
temporary.Add(q);
temporary.Add(r, s);
temporary.Add(t, u, v);
c = temporary;
```

Now it should be clear how you can figure out what to put in the initializer clause:  **look at the type and see what the various Add methods take as arguments**. In your case, the dictionary's Add method takes a key and a value, so the initializer should be `{ { k1, v1 }, { k2, v2 } , ... }`

Make sense?

Comment: You deserve the solve imo. If I see one more 'answer' without context I'm going to start down voting, with a fury. I'll earn the badge "Negative Nancy" if such a thing exists. Keep fighting the good fight!

Answer (score 4):

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>{{"s", "s"}};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>()
    {
        { 1, 1 },
        { 2, 1 },
        { 3, 2 }
    };
```

That will setup a dictionary with three key value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<byte, byte> d = new Dictionary<byte, byte>()
                       { 
                          { 1, 2 }, 
                          { 3, 4 } 
                       };
```